# PS CS6: Confirm and deselect with Escape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

Are there settings in **Photoshop CS6** to confirm and deselect for example a text frame when pressing escape?

By default escape cancels the editing.

Answer (score 1):

This is for CC 2017, but I assume it's the same or similar in CS6.

Go into Preferences, and click the Type item in the menu.

Check the option "Use ESC key to commit text"

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it's not at this point in CS6. There is probably no setting for CS6?

Comment: @Malte have you tried the Enter key, as Scott suggests in his answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Not <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> keys.

Adobe logic is that <kbd>ESC</kbd> means "*never mind*" or "*cancel*" and never "*commit*".

As @BillyKerr points out, Adobe did add a preference option to alter the default behavior for text editing in more recent versions, but that is not going to be helpful for CS6.

Comment: I've always used CMD+Return (Mac) to commit text in a text box. Also good for committing measurements or point sizes etc. in the options bar. (Though now that I'm looking at my keyboard I wonder if that's not just the shortcut for "Enter")

Comment: @GoofyMonkey and Scott, CTRL+Return also works on Win PCs.

Comment: The Command/CTRL+Return is indeed the shortcut for the Enter key... designed for keyboards without the Enter Key (Like Apple's wireless keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

1. Esc to **cancel**
2. Ctrl(Cmd)+Enter(return) to **commit**